# Why is the system tray icon for my program not visible in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, system, nsis

I'm unable to find system tray icon for my program after the installation . I could see that  In Windows XP, it works just fine: the user can launch a program by clicking on the same.

However, in Windows 7 (both Home and Ultimate editions), the icon is not shown in system tray , but it works after I reboot my machine.

I have tried putting the code to [refresh shell icons](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Refresh_shell_icons) in the installer script, but this does not seem to have fixed the problem.

Can anyone help me on this??

PS: I use NSIS script for my installer.

Answer (score 0):

- Is it simply hidden in the pop-up that opens when you click the little arrow?
- If not, is your program actually running at all?
- If your program is running, use Process Explorer to check its integrity level (the Integrity column in Process Explorer). After you reboot and the icon appears, does the process have the same integrity level as when it didn't appear?

Comment: Hi Leo.. while running from finish page of installer it shows integrity null (empty) . But after reboot it shows integrity of medium. how can I elevate process integrity.

Comment: @Andy, That sounds like it already *is* elevated, and that is the actual problem. Run Process Monitor itself elevated and it should say High integrity, right? If so the problem is that your installer is launching your program elevated (because the setup program itself is elevated) when it should not be. (And one consequence is that the taskbar cannot talk to your program as the taskbar is not elevated.) Running things elevated by mistake is a common problem with lots of installers. I'm not sure how you work around it using NSIS but I'm sure you'll find discussions about it as it's so common.

Comment: (You need to run Process Monitor elevated because otherwise it cannot inspect the integrity level of other elevated processes.)